# kendoRendered not always raised

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I'll try to explain my issue as best as I can.

I have an angularjs application with kendoui HTML5 widgets, two different HTML pages (PageOne and PageTwo) and two different controllers.

- PageOne performs a redirect to PageTwo with the following code

  ```
      $location.path("/PageTwo").replace();
  ```
- PageTwo has a listener on the **kendoRendered** event which will display an alert

  ```
      $scope.$on("kendoRendered", (e) => {
          alert("rendered");
      });
  ```

Why the **kendoRendered** event is fired only when the page is loaded (F5) and not after the redirect?

Comment: Could it be that the page is cached; thus, the widgets aren't being recreated (i.e. rendered)?

Comment: Can you use console.log('rendered') instead of alert('rendered') and check if it is not problem with show alert() by browser?

Comment: If I replace alert with console.log the result is the same.

I don't think this is a cache issue. Even when I press the refresh button in my browser (which will not invalidate the cache), the result is the same